# Java: Hexadecimal Issue

Tags: java, parsing, integer, hex

I have the following function, which is immutable:

```
keyCode = Integer.parseInt(array[1], 16);
```

I'm using a different type of constructor than what this function was intended for, and am inputting the actual value I need. As an example, `array[1]` is `83`, but I need `keyCode` to be `83`.

How can I format my input (`83`), so that when it is parsed as above, `keyCode` will be `83`?

Comment: What is the type of `array`?

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what your problem is. If you want output to be the same as input then just use `keyCode=yourInput`. I suspect that this solution is not correct for some reason and I would really like to see this reason as part of your question.

Comment: that's not a function. That's a line of code, which you clearly control. If you need keyCode to be the same as array[1], then make them equal. Or show why you can't do that, because there is no reason for you not to be able to do so based on what you've shown.

Comment: `83` in and of itself doesn't allude to it being a hexadecimal number at all. And, if you were to convert `0x83` to decimal (what `Integer.parseInt()` does), then you would get 131, not 83 in decimal format. Do you want to remove the hexadecimal notation, and leave the actual numbers? Like `0x153` becoming `153` and `0x43` becoming `43`? (Even though the actual conversion to decimal is different.) (PS: `0x` is one way to denote hexadecimal values).

Comment: I think what we'd all like to know (and what's most notably missing from the question) is why you can't just use `keyCode = Integer.parseInt(array[1]);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use [`Integer.toHexString(i)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString%28int%29), or, for a more generic solution, [`Integer.toString(i, radix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int,%20int%29).

```
static void someFunction(String str)
{
   int keyCode = Integer.parseInt(str, 16);
   System.out.println(keyCode); // prints 83
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
   // passing decimal 83 in hex as a string ("53") to the function
   someFunction(Integer.toHexString(83));
}
```

If I'm on the wrong track, please provide a more complete code sample showing what you want to do.

Comment: That basically did it. Just need to convert the hex string to an int.

Comment: Actually, I need to uncheck this. It gives me a `String`, whereas I need an `Integer`. It wasn't as straightforward as I thought. Could you include that conversion?

Comment: The answer *does* include that conversion.  `Integer.toHexString(83)` gives the `String` `"53"`.  `Integer.parseInt("53", 16)` gives the `Integer` `83`.

Comment: To convert any `String` value into an integer, without conversion, use `Integer.parseInt(MY-STRING-HERE)`. Use the method from the above comment to convert to decimal from hexadecimal, then convert to integer.

Comment: More plainly, if you have the `String` `"83"` (please always put quote marks around `String` values so we can tell that's what they are), and you want the `Integer` `83`, then the way you do that is `Integer.parseInt("83");`

Comment: @Adam_G Sorry, I lost you. `parseInt` (which was given in the question) takes a `String` and returns an `int`. Based on that, my function takes a `String`.

Comment: If it produces a large `String` value, like `"4c"`, then `parseInt` doesn't work.

Comment: @Adam_G `4c` is only `76` in decimal, so I'm still not sure what the problem is.